# Use Project As Template

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm an app novice. Using Android Studio 0.4.6 on Windows Vista Home Premium

I have successfully created a very simple webview app. I want to use the same app as a template for creating a unique app for different clients. For each client, I have successfully used refractor to change the project name and module names to reflect the each as a different project for each client.

Despite the changes, the devices on which the apps are installed see all of the separate apps as the same app. I cannot install the app created for one client without deleting or overwriting the installation another.

- What needs to be changed so that each use of the "template" project is recognized as a different and unique app?
- Is there an easy method whereby I can create a project and use it as a "template" for others?
- Is creating the project as a library a correct approach?

Respectfully,
tseroogy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a different package name for your application; that's how Android tells different applications apart. It's in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file (the `com.example.myapp` bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.myapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
```

There's no particularly easy way to make a project into a template. The best you can do is to create your barebones project and duplicate the entire directory and make your changes to individualize it.

If you have a number of APKs you're building that are nearly carbon copies of each other, you could possibly use build flavors to build them all out of one source tree, but if you're new to Android Studio and Gradle and Android development in general, it could be a bit much for you to take on at this point. If you're not afraid of jumping in at the deep end of the pool, you can read up at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors to get an idea of what's involved. Having said that, I'd recommend the copy-and-paste approach in the short term while you get everything else figured out.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. There was a package statement in MainActivity.java, as well. I simply refractored all name changes for the App and Project name and it worked well. Thanks for the link to new build info. I'm noted for diving into the deep end...sometimes I'm lucky. BTW - for this project, all apps are identical except for client information. I change this using variables located in the string.xml.

Comment: Scott, followed your advise on reading up about product-flavor. I was able to use this method to produce multiple apps, each with different versions, using the code from a single project; all without a single hiccup. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly make sense to look at how you could redesign the app so that all of the key features are in a single library, and all of the custom features are in an application project that references that library. That way, any new features that are added to the library will also be included each of the variants.

I suspect that the you having trouble installing the all of the apps at the same time because they are signed with the same key. If you havn't already, create a new key for each version and sign it each one with a different key.

Creating a custom template for the IDE may be possible using maven http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html although I've no idea if this works with Android Studio or not, I'm still on Eclipse.

Comment: You don't need a different key for each version. And Maven archetypes won't work.

Comment: Appreciate the recommendations. The apps are identical except for the client information. Same key was used.